# Peek messages does not return all messages

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I have the logic below that I am using to peek at the messages on a subscription

```
var path = EntityNameHelper.FormatSubscriptionPath(TopicName, subscriptionName);
var receiver = new MessageReceiver(connection string, path);
var messages = await receiver.PeekAsync(1000);
```

When I look at Service Bus Explorer it shows that there are 800 messages on the subscription

However the logic only returns 23

Does anyone know why this happens, is there some kind of caching or something?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

That's by design. Peek and receive operations will return as much as broker can at that specific moment. If you want to retrieve all the messages, you'd have to write some code to iterate over the request one or more time until the number of items you need is reached.

If you want to raise a broker request to clarify this, there's a service issue tracker [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues).

Comment: I want to read all of the messages how will I know if I have read them all?

Comment: The same way you knew there were 800 messages. In general, if you have a continuous flow of messages, processing a large batch is undesirable. There are better techniques.

Comment: I only know that because of service bus explorer

Comment: Ah, I see. The message count is available on the queue as a metadata. That's how SBExolorer does it as well.